# Parsing a non-excel excel file

Tags: php, import-from-excel

So I've got the method of grabbing the information. That portion's not hard:

```
    <?php
$aid = file_get_contents(http://www.cybernations.net/assets/CyberNations_SE_Aid_Stats_3132015520002.zipl);
$war = file_get_contents(http://www.cybernations.net/assets/CyberNations_SE_War_Stats_3132015525002.zip);
$nation = file_get_contents(http://www.cybernations.net/assets/CyberNations_SE_Nation_Stats_3132015510002.zip);
?>
```

What I'm having a lot of trouble with, is figuring out how to take that information and parse it for what I want. It's an excel file saved as a .txt and what I need to do is grab the columns and put them into an SQL table. Once I have the columns I can handle the SQL portion, though.

Answer (score 0):

Get the first line of the csv by using something like `substr($aid, 0, strpos($aid, "\n"))`.

The `strpos($aid, "\n")` will find the first occurrence of the newline (\n) character. Then you get the substring from the beginning of the string to that character, which will return the first line of your string.

From there you can use `explode()` to split the string into an array of column names using the pipe delimiter present in your files.

Example:

```
<?php

    $aid = file_get_contents('http://www.cybernations.net/assets/CyberNations_SE_Aid_Stats_3132015520002.zip');
    $war = file_get_contents('http://www.cybernations.net/assets/CyberNations_SE_War_Stats_3132015525002.zip');
    $nation = file_get_contents('http://www.cybernations.net/assets/CyberNations_SE_Nation_Stats_3132015510002.zip');

    $aid_columns = array_filter(explode("|", substr($aid, 0, strpos($aid, "\n"))));
?>
```

The `array_filter` will remove all whitespaces (since your columns end with a pipe delimiter), this way you do not end up with "empty" columns in the resulting array.